# Get version of Installed Software on remote machine

Tags: powershell

I am trying a write an application to fetch the version of the application installed on remote machines. There is a need to query many remote servers and get the version of the application and show it on the dashboard.
Powershell WMI takes too long to get the information. I am looking for something lot faster.

The app will read remote server information like IP, Username, and password from a config file and fetch the data.

Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to take a closer look at [Powershell Sessions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pssessions).

There are at least two ways to approach in from there, one is using `Invoke-Command` in combination with the `-ComputerName` attribute, possibly along with `-Authentication` or `-Credential`. `-ScriptBlock` contains the code you want to run.

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName "computername.domain.local" -ScriptBlock { ... }
```

I assume from "the application" that your concern is one application, and not every application. Then you should be able to tell the version by running `Get-Item` on the executable, then look at either `VersionInfo.ProductVersion` or `VersionInfo.FileVersion`, whichever is more relevant to your case.

To access one of them, you could use something like:

```
$version = (Get-Item "path-to-executable\executable.exe').VersionInfo.ProductVersion
```

To find out which attributes are relevant to your executable, you can run

```
Get-Item "executable.exe" | Select -ExpandProperty VersionInfo | Format-List *
```

Combining these techniques, you could try something like this.

```
# this is a dummy array for example purposes
$computers = @(@{'ip' = '127.0.0.1'; 'username' = 'admin'; 'password' = 'password'})

foreach($computer in $computers)
{
    # creating a PSCredential object from plain text passwords is not a good practice, but I'm assuming here that's what you've got to work with
    $credentials = [System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]::new($computer.username, (ConvertTo-SecureString -String $computer.password -AsPlainText -Force))
    # fetch versioninfo info from remote computer
    $versioninfo = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computer.ip -Credential $credentials -ScriptBlock { Get-Item "executable.exe" | Select -ExpandProperty VersionInfo
    if ($versioninfo.ProductVersion -ne '3.1.2414.0')
    {
        # do something if product version isn't 3.1.2414.0
    }
    if ($versioninfo.ProductVersionRaw.Major -lt 5)
    {
        # do something if product version major part is less than 5 (true for 1.5.5.5 but false for 5.1.1.1)
    }
}
```

If you want to run several commands on the client computers, use `New-PSSession` and pass the session along to every call to `Invoke-Command`, otherwise you'd lose time and resources opening a new session every time.
Here's an example on how that could be achieved:

```
$session = New-PSSession -ComputerName $computer.ip -Credential $credentials
$versioninfo = Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock { # do something }
if ($versioninfo.ProductVersion -lt 1)
{
    Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock { # do something else }
}
Remove-PSSession -Session $session
```

You might also want to check out [the using: scope modifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes#the-using-scope-modifier) if you find a need to pass variables along to the remote computer, which would make `$localvariable` visible at the remote computer with `$using:localvariable` (readonly)

If time is still a concern after this (especially with tcp timeouts on offline hosts), then threading is the next topic you'd want to look into.

As far as I know, my code is compatible with Powershell v3.1, but I recommend using no less than v5, especially on the machine running the script.

This should be enough information to send you on your way. Good luck. :)